# Finding the points in which a smooth surface is regular

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I've been given a surface $\sigma(u,v) = (4u,3u,5\sqrt{1-v^2})$ with $u\in\mathbb{R}$, $v \in]-1,1[$ and asked to find the points in which the surface is regular.

I've tried to find these points graphically (critical points) but to no avail. How can I solve this through formulas?

Comment: Are you sure about the definition of $\sigma$?

Comment: What is the definition of regular surface ?

Answer (score 0):

Given $\phi : U \to \mathbb{R}^3$

$\phi (u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$

The points on the surface which are regular (say P), are those where the matrix $\partial_\phi(P)$ has rank 2.
This is also equivalent to say that the columns must be independent vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

A further explanation can be found here: [http://uregina.ca/~mareal/cs3.pdf](http://uregina.ca/%7Emareal/cs3.pdf) (second page)